# Inserting php output in an html file

Tags: php

I saw some html that displays the results of a PHP code just by adding {#name}

```
<html>
  <body>
     {#name}
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i do that?

I have been looking around and I cant find anything that shows me how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: probably used together with a templating system...

Comment: That's not PHP, so it must be part of a templating system that happens to use PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you saw was probably some sort of template system. If that is the case, the PHP script reads the template, and then replaces all instances of `{#name}` with the contents of the variable `$name`.

An example of one such template system would be [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/crash_course).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?=$name?>
```

where name is your php variable

Comment: Note that this requires either PHP 5.4, or that `short_tags` be `On` in the PHP configuration.